# Set notation for indices

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have created a set notation in which I am uncertain whether this is formally correct or not. It is about the set of all indices of the data points that fulfill a certain equation:

$\mathbb{S} = \{i \; | \; y^{(i)}(\beta^{T} \cdot x^{(i)} + b) -1 = 0 \;,  \forall i = 1,...,M\}$

The question is if the 'i' in the left part of the set actually refers to the indices or if I have to formulate it differently?

Comment: It does not make sense to define a set of all indices $i$ such that for all $i$ some condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{S} = \{i \; | \; y^{(i)}(\beta^{T} \cdot x^{(i)} + b) -1 = 0 \;,  i \in \{ 1,...,M\}\}$
corrects your mistake.

Comment: Thank you. One more question, just out of curiosity does the order matter in the 'right / conditional' part of the set? Strictly speaking the 'i`s' are not defined in the equation if their definition comes in the second place?

Comment: And another question: If I would write the set as $\mathbb{S} = \{x \; | y^{(i)}...=0 \;, i \in \{1,...,M\} \}$ would it still refer to the indices, or does it matter to specifically choose (in this case) the letter 'i' in order to refer to them?

Comment: It is a set of x's. @xvzwx

Comment: {1,2,.. M} is unordered.